# How to include hierarchy in JSON for Android?

Tags: android, json

I have this JSON file that I would like to send to a server with  POST

```
{
    "header1" : {
        "message" : {
           "content" : "Hello",
           "type" : "text"
        },
        "header2" : {
           "address" : "sample@example.com"
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code I have for the json pbject
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

```
            jsonObject.put("content", "hello");
            jsonObject.put("type", "text");
            jsonObject.put("address", "sample@example.com");
            String message = jsonObject.toString();
```

My question is how do I code the hierarchy: header1, message and header2?

Answer (score 1):

```
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject messageObject = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject header2Object = new JSONObject();
    try {

        messageObject .put("content", "Hello");
        messageObject .put("type", "text");

        header2Object .put("address", "sample@example.com");

        json.put("header1", messageObject.tostring);
        json.put("header2", header2Object.tostring );
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
```

Try This

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do this in a *bottom up* fashion.

What I mean is first make a JSONObject with the name `header2` and put `address` in it.

Then make the other JSONObject named `message`, populate it using `put` and then in turn place it inside another JSONObject named `header1`.

```
JSONObject header2 = new JSONObject ();
header2.put("address", "your address");
```

Then,

```
JSONObject header1 = new JSONObject ();
header1.put("header2", header2);
```

And so on...